# Add string elements to a list

Tags: python, string, list, join, append

I want to add the string elements from a for loop into a list (for every iteration) and keep unique string values as well,

```
#Script will give an output in order to count occurence of BGC clusters per Bacteria Type

#!/usr/bin/env python
from Bio import SeqIO 
#Biopython package for input file (input and output assorted sequence file formats)
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd

# Set the input file to be used and the output file to be written to
gbk_file = "E2N166_1.final.gbk" #example: "contig_1.final.gbk"
tsv_file = "cluster_count_file.txt"  #output file can be .csv, .txt etc...
cluster_output = open(tsv_file, "w")

#Extract the Cluster info from GBK file,
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(gbk_file, "genbank"):
    cluster_list = []
    for seq_feat in seq_record.features:
        if seq_feat.type == "cluster":
            cluster_number = seq_feat.qualifiers["note"][0].replace(" ","_").replace(":","")
            cluster_type = seq_feat.qualifiers["product"][0]
            cluster_list.append(cluster_type)

            cluster_out.write("#" + cluster_number+ "\tCluster Type:" + cluster_type + "\n")

print("File Cluster Out")
```

The output looks as following [Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trzFA.png)

Comment: `cluster_out` is used without declaration, and I do not know what question you have. Please illustrate what difficulty you're facing.

Comment: cluster_out is just the output file, that is fine. I just want to take each string element from cluster_type and append to a list as I am trying to do with cluster_list. I want to keep unique items in list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store unique elements, i suggest you to use set instead of list. (You must know that set is not ordered)

```
cluster_set = set()
```

But if you want to persist on using list, you can do this:

```
if cluster_type not in cluster_list:
    cluster_list.append(cluster_type)
```

Comment: thank you so much, with the set it worked perfectly fine :)